# Error al instalar libreras en r ( as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Tags: linux, r

Buen día
Actualice r y ahora cuando intento instalar cualquier librería con el comando **install.packages("NOMBRE_DEL_PAQUETE")** pero me aparece el siguiente error, cabe aclarar que estoy usando la terminal de Linux.

```
Installing package into ‘/home/usuario/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

Comment: Bienvenido Alexander a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Falta bastante información como para poder ayudarte: ¿Que paquete estás queriendo instalar? ¿Que comando ejecutas? Luego información de tu sesión, que podrías agregar desde la salida de `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Hola, Gracias por sus comentarios los tendré en cuenta, espero mejorar pronto.

Answer (score 1):

No es un error, es solo una advertencia. Te esta informando que como no tienes el `lib` definido, va a instalar el paquete en el path por defecto: `/home/usuario/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6`.

No significa que haya ningun problema, no te preocupes. Todo funciona bien!